# Problema con commandButton en Netbeans

Tags: java, jsf

Tengo un problema... no entiendo porque no aparecen los botones en la vista :(

```html
<h:body>
        <h:form id="frmPrincipal">
            <p:dataTable>
                <p:column headerText="Boton1">
                    <p:commandButton value="1"/>                    
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Boton2">
                    <p:commandButton value="2"/>
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
```

Comment: Hola María. Bienvenida. Has de quitar la foto y sustituirla por texto para que sea mas facil de leer y poder copiar y pegarlo. Edita tambien el titulo para que no sea en mayusculas, queda muy abusivo

Comment: Quita el p:datatable, esa etiqueta es para mostrar una tabla a partir de una lista de elementos, que además no especificas, no para maquetación.

Comment: Gracias  y ahora corrijo esas cosas :)

Answer (score 1):

Una manera correcta de dejar tu código sin p:datatable sería:

```
<p:layout>
    <p:layoutUnit position="west">
        <p:commandButton value="1"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="right">
        <p:commandButton value="2"/>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Puedes usar las propiedades size, min-width, min-height, style de p:layout y p:layoutUnit para maquetar segun tus necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta insertar  los botones con este código:

```html
 <button type="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Comment: Seguirían sin salir, ya que al estar vacía la colección del p:datatable no se pintaría ninguna fila.